# Update 50K+ records in a table *at once* using SqlAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

#### Background

I'm working with a table *(in a postgres db)*, let's call it `Person`. It is related to a table, `JobTitle` through the association table `PersonJobTitleAssociation`. *(Each person can have many job titles.)*

```py
engine = create_engine(DB_URI)
Base = declarative_base(engine)

class Person(Base):
   __tablename__ = 'person'
   id = Column(Integer, unique=True, primary_key=True)
   name = Column(String, unique=False)
   
   # relationship with all job_titles
   all_job_titles = relationship('JobTitle',
       secondary='person_job_title_association', 
       order_by='desc(person_job_title_association.c.date_created)')
   
   # Update this
   magic_value = Column(String, unique=False)


class PersonJobTitleAssociation(Base):
   __tablename__ = 'person_job_title_association'
   person_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('person.id'), primary_key=True)
   job_title_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('job_title.id'), primary_key=True)
   date_created = Column(DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.datetime.utcnow)

class JobTitle(Base):
   __tablename__ = 'job_title'
   id = Column(Integer, unique=True, primary_key=True)
   name = Column(String, unique=True)


# Once everything is declared, bind to the session
session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)()
```

#### Problem

I'd like to access each `Person` and their most recent `JobTitle` and perform `some_magic_function()` to this person's `name` and `job title`. *(Mask for "some operation which must be done in python")*.

```
import random
import string

def some_magic_function(name, job_title):
   """This operation must be done in python"""
   # Update the job_title if blank
   if not job_title:
      job_title = 'unspecified'

   # Get a random character and check if it's in our person's name
   char = random.choice(string.ascii_letters)
   
   if char in name:
      return job_title.upper()
   else:
      return job_title.lower()
```

**I'm updating values like so:**

*(Let's pretend this query is optimized and doesn't need to be improved)*

```py
query = session.query(Person)\
    .options(joinedload(Person.all_job_titles))\
    .order_by(Person.id)

# operate on all people
for person in query:
   
   # Get and set the magic value
   magic_value = some_magic_function(person.name, person.all_job_titles[0])
   if person.magic_value != magic_value:
       person.magic_value = magic_value

# Finally, once complete, commit the session
session.commit()
```

#### Issue

Querying and updating values is pretty fast on the python side. But things get real slow when calling `session.commit()`. Did some research, it appears `sqlalchemy` is locking the entire `person` table each time it updates a value. Further, each update is executed as its own command. *(That's 50K independent SQL commands for 50K records.)*

#### Desired outcome

***I'd love a pythonic solution which would update all 50K records in "one swoop."***

I've considered utilizing a `read_only` session, then passing update values into an array of tuples and sending updates through an `with_updates` session. This seems like a more SQL friendly approach, but is a bit heavy handed and unstraightforward.

Much appreciated!

Comment: As a general approach, produce a temporary table of changes one way or the other (`CREATE`, `VALUES`, union, from JSON, ...), allowing you to bulk send the changes, and do a joined update from it.

Comment: Interesting. Would love if you could share more details on this @IljaEverilä

Comment: Have a look at https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.Session.bulk_save_objects

Comment: Helpful @JesseBakker --> applying this isn't as straightfoward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be able to reduce the number of round trips to the database by simply enabling [batch fast execution helper](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/dialects/postgresql.html#psycopg2-fast-execution-helpers), but as a more explicit approach produce a temporary/derived table of changes one way or the other:

- `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE` and `COPY`
- `(VALUES ...) AS ...`, possibly combined with explicit use of [`execute_values()`](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/extras.html#psycopg2.extras.execute_values)
- `unnest()` an array of rows
- from JSON using `json(b)_to_recordset()`

allowing you to bulk send the changes, and do `UPDATE ... FROM`:

```
import csv
from io import StringIO

# Pretending that the query is optimized and deterministic
query = session.query(Person)\
    .options(joinedload(Person.all_job_titles))\
    .order_by(Person.id)

# Prepare data for COPY
changes_csv = StringIO()
changes_writer = csv.writer(changes_csv)
for p in query:
    mv = some_magic_function(p.name, p.all_job_titles[0])
    if p.magic_value != mv:
        changes_writer.writerow((p.id, mv))

changes_csv.seek(0)

session.execute("""
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE new_magic (
        person_id INTEGER, 
        value TEXT
    ) ON COMMIT DROP
""")

# Access the underlying psycopg2 connection directly to obtain a cursor
with session.connection().connection.cursor() as cur:
    stmt = "COPY new_magic FROM STDIN WITH CSV"
    cur.copy_expert(stmt, changes_csv)

# Make sure that the planner has proper statistics to work with
session.execute("ANALYZE new_magic ( person_id )")
session.execute("""
    UPDATE person
    SET magic_value = new_magic.value
    FROM new_magic
    WHERE person.id = new_magic.person_id
""")
session.commit()
```

Not exactly "Pythonic" in the sense that it does not let the ORM figure out what to do, but on the other hand explicit is better than implicit.